# Communicate with a desktop application

Tags: sockets

Wanted to see if this is possible.  I have an application on my desktop, for now lets just say its putty.exe.  Is there any way using code I can open this application, enter the host name into the field, and then connect to the host?

This is something that will need to be done without an API because the application I need to open does not have one.  What I need to try and do via code is basically open it and log in.

Would this be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many apps ([including PuTTY](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)) allow you to pass commands or options when you start up the application. It depends entirely on the exact program you're talking about, though--some have limited control from the command line, and some have none at all.

Because the command line is not a particularly secure place to pass sensitive data, it is unlikely that "logging in" from the command line will be supported, at least if a password is required.

Barring that, there are a variety of external macro or script tools you can use, such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/); these allow you to issue keystrokes and button presses to arbitrary windows or applications, even those without an accessible script interface or API.  Beware that it can be fragile to script against an application you don't control, as any application updates may cause the UI to change and consequently cause your scripts to break.

---

N.B. I haven't used or contributed to AutoHotkey, and can't vouch for its security nor its usefulness, but it illustrates the point. I'm sure there are a variety of "macro programs" that would fit your needs, but you'd be best served with a magazine article or web search--StackOverflow is not a great place to solicit recommendations for specific pieces of software.